# round a number to n decimal use format show different result

Tags: java, android, rounding

when I use format to get round value

```
".1f".format(0.55)
```

in some devices get result  some samsung android 6.0

```
0.5
```

and other devices get result

```
0.6
```

if the value is 0.56
result is the same

```
0.6
```

It's that a bug, so I replace with that

```
val scale = 10.0.pow(2.0)
return ((round(0.55 * scale) / scale).toFloat())
```

Answer (score 1):

Are all the devices you test this on using the same locale?

You can use `NumberFormat` class with explicit rounding mode to ensure the same rounding rules:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);    //rounding rules

nf.format(0.55d);
```